# How to load already built in Magento project to localhost with database?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have to customize some of the things in already built in magento project. I copied the source file and pasted in htdocs folder and loaded the sql file in database. Modified host,username,password,dbname in the xml file which is situated in app/etc/local.xml folder. Which is as follows

```
<config>
<global>
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Thu, 20 Dec 2012 04:20:32 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[1dba174377df948cc045234de2d2d959]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>

                <dbname><![CDATA[btrweb]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Now when I load the file as localhost/btrweb(projectname) it is throwing an error like

**SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'directory_country' already exists**

Could you please help me out from this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I should say the best way is using a versioning system like Git! In this way you can simply clone your repositories anywhere you want.

In your case I think your problem is due to the way you moved (dumped/imported) your DB in the localhost DB. In general in Magento each module (that has interactions with DB) holds a sql folder with file(s) inside that track DB changes in the history of that module. All files in this folder run sequentially (after running each file magento adds its version to a table (named: *core_resource*); in this way Magento knows which file was already run and avoids re-running it. In your case the directory module of Magento -> (you can find it in: *core/Mage/Directory*) is failing to run one of these scripts and therefore throwing that error. You can whether try to restore your DB (highly recommended) or try this way: `DELETE * FROM core_resource WHERE code = "directory_setup"` (remove all the Magento cache). In first reload of any page Magento will automatically run all the scripts in that sql folder again and this might fix your problem.

P.S: Don't forget you need to update *core_config_data* table as well, with *secure_url* and *unsecure_url* to point to your alias in localhost.

Comment: @Hatef-->There has no such 'code=directory_setup' in "core_resource" table.

Comment: @Sudheer Just to make sure, you mean "directory_setup" doesn't exist under "code" column of "core_resource" table?!!

Comment: yes it doesn't exist. My database size is greater than 20MB, it is not properly importing all the data, so what are the changes need to be done to import database properly?

Comment: @Sudheer yes I've guessed so! First drop your current DB. Then make a complete dump of your source DB (_Dump Structure and Data_) and then import. Don't use web interface for importing big databases because it most probably ends with a timeout and a broken DB. I personally use MySql Workbench for both (export, import) operations. You can download it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ Install and open the software -> Create your connection to DB -> Open the connection -> You can find Data Export (Import) under Management section.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It works for me. I don't have enough reputations to vote u up.. Thanks once again.